# Google assistant is not playing my daily breafing

Tags: 7.1-nougat, google-assistant

I am using google assistant on my **Moto e4 plus** running on **Android 7.1.1**. 
I found some cool tricks to do with google assistant in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KVJcz3bR4Yo), and I found that when I say `How's my day look like` to google assistant, it starts playing my daily briefing.

[image]

But the problem is that there is no sound, just the text. For other commands and questions, it works fine.
What could be the problem, and how can I fix it to make google assistant work properly?

Please tell me if any more information required.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you.
This happens because of the phone's language, that doesn't support google assistant properly.

Change your device language to **English United State** by navigating to `Settings > Languages & Input > Languages > Add a language` and then search for English United State or English US and add that language. Also, make it default language for your phone by dragging it to top from languages menu back in `Settings > Languages & Input > Languages`. Then close google assistant and open again. It will work. You will find some change in its voice.

Hope it helps. :)

Source: [Google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/ZXNzps_ul_s)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But what was the problem with Indian English?